# Unable to install espeak software

Tags: 13.10, espeak

Whenever I try to install espeak using apt-get install espeak it shows

```
umang@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ apt-get install espeak
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
umang@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install espeak
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
espeak is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  calibre-bin fonts-mathjax libchm1 libjs-jquery libjs-mathjax libjs-sphinxdoc
  libjs-underscore libpodofo0.9.0 libtidy-0.99-0 python-beautifulsoup
  python-cherrypy3 python-cssselect python-cssutils python-dateutil
  python-dnspython python-feedparser python-markdown python-mechanize
  python-netifaces python-pygments python-pyparsing python-repoze.lru
  python-routes python-utidylib python-webob
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
umang@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ clear
```

I have used Desktop as the folder because espeak package is present in this folder.
I have also try it after going to root using
sudo -s

But still the same thing occurs.

can you please suggest me some correcting measures?

Answer (score 0):

`espeak` package was already installed on your pc.Run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to Remove automatically all unused packages.

Answer (score 0):

The speech synthesizer  [espeak](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/espeak) [image: Install espeak] is installed by default in Ubuntu releases up to 12.04. LTS. No need to install them there.

To use this application open a terminal and type:

```
espeak "Hello World. This is an example."
```

There are many options including speed or pitch of results (see [manpage of espeak](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/espeak.1.html)).

In later Ubuntu releases **espeak** was replaced by [spd-say](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/spd-say.1.html) which has some more options.